# Nginx : Throw customized error page for no live upstream while connecting to upstream

Tags: nginx, custom-error-pages, nginx-location

Following is the upstream block I have in Nginx

```
upstream sample{
    server abc1.example.com down;
    server abd2.example.com down;
}
```

In this case error logs show the following error :

```
no live upstreams while connecting to upstream, client: 10.196.90.83, server: abc_sample_a , request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://sample/", host: "abc_sample_a
```

Currently, the error code received is 502. But I want to return 503 error code.

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
server {
  ...
  error_page 502 = @fallback;

  ...

  location @fallback {
    return 503;
  }
}
```

Comment: My upstream block is in a separate file and referred using proxy_pass directive by many other files. i don't want to republish all files with this error code fall back. Also, it need to fallback only if all servers are down. not it application itself returns 502.

Comment: You may add this code in the main nginx config at the http block for this case, than it will handle all you sites.

Comment: Also you may set:  proxy_intercept_errors on; Than nginx woldn't handle apps errors with error_page. http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_intercept_errors